# object_id and link fields are missing in "{page_id}/posts" request

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I request latest posts published by public page with request:

```
    /{group_id}/posts?fields=object_id&limit=1
```

and for some posts there are "object_id" field returned and for others are not. Why do this happen? Are any special rules for posting posts in page?

Through Graph Explorer it looks http://take.ms/12LuG. But viewing with Graph API Explorer token is fine: every object_id is returned.

I need "object_id" or "link" fields to show latest page post inside the canvas game.

Found similar problem here [Facebook Graph API object_id missing sometimes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19270801/facebook-graph-api-object-id-missing-sometimes). But the person who posts news in the page swears all posts are posted similar with no difference. What can be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

As of the docs at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/post/#fields, the `object_id` field is only filled when the post has a photo or a video referenced:

> The ID of any uploaded photo or video attached to the post.

Comment: Thanks for response.
I'm sure there is a photo or video in every post. Also when i look request in Graph Explorer i see object_id from looking with Graph API explorer token. It is missing only with application token.
I also tried this request with app token with all permission checked - still no success.